# Is it possible to use a bean generated from the same class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

I'm trying to use a bean generated from the same class. E.g:

```java
public class Test {
  ...


  @Bean
  public Dog dog() {
    ...
    return dog;
  }

  @Bean
  public DogHouse dogHouse() {
    Dog d = dog(); // Is this right? Can I inject dog bean here?
    ...
    return dogHouse;
  }
}
```

Two requirements I got to obey:

- Use the result of `dog()` in `dogHouse()`
- Keep `dog()` and `dogHouse()` in the same java class

Is this possible? If it is, how should I inject the dog Bean in Test class? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Bean
  public DogHouse dogHouse() {
    Dog d = dog();
    ...
    return dogHouse;
  }
```

When @Bean have dependencies on one another, then to resolve this dependency one bean method can call the other one. In your case calling **dog()** inside **dogHouse()** is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an argument injection to let spring know that the `DogHouse` bean requires the `Dog` bean.

```
@Bean
public DogHouse dogHouse(Dog d) {
  ...
  return dogHouse;
}
```

Spring will inject the `Dog` bean into the method while constructing the `DogHouse` bean.